# RegEx: How to exclude the first two characters from selection

Tags: regex

If you look at this text:
`FIRST TEXT (IF CAPS AND IF IT ENDS WITH A PERIOD) SHOULD BE EXCLUDED. Here comes all the text we want to grab. And the ONLY problem with our current regular expression is that it also includes the period and space in front of this text. Does anyone know how to fix it so we grab from "Here comes..." and not ". Here comes..."? Thank you.`

My current regular expression looks like this: (?![A-ZÆØÅ!´'/0-9\s()]+[.])[^=]*

- But I simply can't figure out how to exclude the first ". " from the selection. Can anyone please help? You can try it out here:
  https://regex101.com/r/UpRlOV/3

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/7nd9aR/1

Comment: Hi Wiktor! This almost works. But if you notice my test-example - here it will not exclude the first text before the period if it contains non-capitalized characters. Yours just excludes all before first period.

Comment: Good, use [`(?![A-ZÆØÅ!´'\/0-9\s()]+[.])(?:\.\s*)?([^=]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/7nd9aR/2) - your value is in Group 1. Or [`(?![A-ZÆØÅ!´'\/0-9\s()]+[.])(?:\.\s*)?\K[^=]+`](https://regex101.com/r/7nd9aR/3)

Comment: @Jan2000 Here's a correction to that idea: `^(?:[A-ZÆØÅ!´'\/0-9\s()]+\. )?\K[^=]+`

Comment: Is that for a PCRE regex engine, by the way?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes its for PCRE. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot and spaces are matched because your lookahead pattern does not match only up to the dot. To make sure your match does not start with `.` + space(s), you may consume them if they are present. An optional non-capturing group is quite handy in such situations:

```
(?![A-ZÆØÅ!´'\/0-9\s()]+[.])(?:\.\s*)?\K[^=]+
                            ^^^     ^^
```

or, if your regex engine does not support `\K` match reset operator, use a capturing group:

```
(?![A-ZÆØÅ!´'\/0-9\s()]+[.])(?:\.\s*)?([^=]+)
                                      ^     ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7nd9aR/3).

Answer (score 0):

`.+?\.(.+)`

Is something like this what you're looking for?

this way you can just grab group 1 from the result

https://regex101.com/r/1Eo38B/1

Comment: Hi Tomos - thank you for your reply! First: This still grabs the first whitespace. And second: I would really like if you could begin with my regEx because yours just excludes everything until first period (I have some rules for when to exclude that).